# iphone app updation issue

Tags: iphone, installation, app-store, new-operator

I have uploaded new version of app successfully to app store...problem I am facing is

If I am deleting the existing app in iPhone and install newly every thing works fine but..If I update without deleting the existing app it throws me error **"app is not updated please restart the app"**

In short user who is already having the app and if he updates then he will see the error..but for new user everything works fine..

Please help me what can be the possible problem??

**EDIT: Added a new table in Database so when we update the existing app its not overwriting previous data base..any suggestions???**

Comment: My previous version stores data in ~/Documents folder..new update(having change in DB ) is unable to overwrite data in the folder...

Thanks & Regards
Narasimha Reddy

Comment: changes made to newly updated app include database changes..will that lead to any problem??

Comment: are you using core data?

Comment: Not familiar with term core data..

Comment: I would say NO.. we are not using it

Comment: Have you tested update ?

Comment: yes..I tested it..Anyways i got the issue..trying for solution..

Comment: Keep calm... issue apologie to users, explain the situation and send a new binary to app-store. i've seen that happen many times and users tend to forgive IF you act promptly. if you need help with deleting/overwriting/updating database in your documents folder i can help you tommorow (i'm not at mac at the moment) but i'm sure you'll find a solution sooner. Just don't panic and notify your users (you can do that in your app's description in app store). Sure you'll get some bad reviews but if you app is any good they soon won't matter anymore - i mean reviews, not users :).

Comment: One more thing: with next update keep in mind that it has to cope with both previous versions.

Comment: thnks..please help me in updating database in your documents folder

Answer (score 0):

If you've made changes to data storage like SQL database that ships with your app, you need to manually make the changes on existing versions of the app.
So youd check if a new table exists in the database, and create it if it doesn't. This way the user can keep there existing data.

Once you've shipped an app, you have to keep this version in mind whenever updating.